# UISlider Update UITextField - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a UISlider that I want to update a UITextField for the value of 1-100 in real time, i.e. I slide the slider and the value updates.

How can I do this? I couldn't find anything in the class reference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to listen for value changes on the slider. You can set this up in interface builder or in code.

```
//Add event for valueChanged in viewDidLoad
[self.slider addTarget:self 
                action:@selector(sliderValueChanged:) 
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

...

-(void)sliderValueChanged:(id)sender
{
    self.textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 
                             (int)(slider.value * 99) + 1];
}
```

Comment: Hey You know Android as well right? I am keen to learn Android development. Can you please give some invaluable tips on how I can start with Android development and which are the books  should refer to?

Comment: I learned everything just using the documentation since I already had Java experience. (Of course StackOverflow helps as well) http://developer.android.com/resources/index.htm

Comment: should the addTarget go in init?

Comment: @SuperString `init` is too soon, it needs to go into `-(void)viewDidLoad;`